# Monitor blinking with power light is on

Tags: graphics-card, display, power-supply

The blinking of monitor occurs after prolonged usage, typically after 3 hours. Following steps are performed for the debugging.

1. The monitor is checked with different hdmi/vga cable.
2. The monitor is checked with the second PC. The monitor works fine. Hence it is confirmed that the monitor is working fine.
3. The graphic drivers are updated. However, still, I am getting a blinking screen.

Is it a graphics card problem? or motherboard or PSU??

My PSU is 450 Watts. The PC configuration is following:

Asus 320 M-K, PSU of 450 watts, 8 Gb ram, Ryzen R5 1600 procesor. 1TB hard disk, 256 GB ssd

Comment: What model is the monitor?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention. Dell P2419H.

Comment: Does the problem occur when the system is idle, or under high load video load?

Comment: Yes, this occurs even when the system is idle or under normal load like web browsing.

Comment: If the environment is relatively hot, this might be a problem of temperature?

Comment: Maybe, but its relatively cold.

Comment: I will add one more fan to cpu chassis. But PSU is sufficient? my friend was telling that maybe its power supply problem, as it might not be sufficient.

Comment: @harrymc, I have added an extra fan to my chassis, still, the problem persists. Is it time to buy a new graphics card?

Comment: I don't think so, if it works fine for three hours. Maybe power fluctuations if you don't have a UPS (although why only after 3 hours). Perhaps a repair-shop will have the tools to analyze the problem.

Comment: @harrymc, I have UPS. I will give the CPU to repair shop. The only problem is that here, the repair guys are not reliable.

Comment: Update: I gave graphics card to the service center. They replaced graphics card and now my monitor and PC is working fine :) Thank you @harrymc, davidgo, and wrecclesham